# how can i get a specific data for a user from firebase in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a user info database and observe them by using firebase for every single user. the creation part went good I think but when I call the `observeSingleEvent` and print the snapshot value, it says that the snapshot is null. Can you guys help me with that?

here is what my firebase database console shows;

```
>sinav-be280
>>member
>>>'SffbOC1UoYcmfBNCrjn2aOhFM4F2'
>>>>mail: "1@1.com"

>>>>name: "1"

>>>>password: "123123"

>>>>phone: "1"
```

here is my code

```
func createUserIfno() {
  let userInfoDB = ref.child("member")

  let userDictionary = [
    "name": self.nameTextView.text!,
    "phone": self.phoneNumberTextField.text!,
    "mail": Auth.auth().currentUser ? .email!,
    "password" : self.passwordTextField.text!,
  ]
  userInfoDB.child(userID!).setValue(userDictionary) {
    (error, reference) in

    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
    } else {
      print("info saved")
    }
  }
}

func printUserInfo() {
  let userInfoDB = ref.child("member").child(userID!)
  userInfoDB.keepSynced(true)
  userInfoDB.observeSingleEvent( of: .value, with: {
    (snapshot) in
    if !snapshot.exists() {

      print("snapshot does exist")
      print(snapshot)
      return
    }
  })
}
```

it says ;

```
snapshot does exist
Snap (1jMpyCCbt0crfUdINnlSupRdcqk1) <null>
```

and I don't even know what is the `1jMpyCCbt0crfUdINnlSupRdcqk1` id.

Comment: When do you call `printUserInfo()`?

Comment: in the viewDidLoad

Comment: (snapshot , error) in   and print error and see what it actually say

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually i played with the code a little and solved the problem.

In my app i wrote the code for creating a user and creating a database separately so in firebase, somehow first user id goes to second user's info list and second goes the third. So i called my createUserInfo func within the createUser func and problem solved.